# Marcar Todas Checkbox em um groupbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um programa que em um groupbox tem várias checkbox, como são muitas e pensei em fazer um botão para selecionar todas de uma vez, para ser mais prático, mas ai surgiu uma duvida, como posso fazer com que ao clicar no botão automaticamente selecione todas, e que eu não precise fazer um `CheckBox.Checked = true;` para todas?

Comment: Deu certo, a resposta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No botão busca esse `GroupBox` (no meu exemplo é `groupBox1`) e pegue os seus controles que são do tipo `CheckBox` (`Cast<>`) e faça um `ForEach` setando a sua propriedade `Checked = true`, exemplo:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    groupBox1.Controls.Cast<CheckBox>()
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x => x.Checked = true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mais uma solução caso o groupbox não contenha apenas checkboxs:

```
groupBox1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().All(chk => chk.Checked = true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Geralmente faço assim:

```
foreach (Control ctl in Gbx.Controls)
{
  if (ctl is CheckBox)
  ((CheckBox)ctl).Checked = true;
}
```